# QT Q3Dsurface to display palne

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display a 3d data by using qt Q3DSurface,here is the code:

```
Q3DSurface *graph = new Q3DSurface();
graph->setFlags(graph->flags() ^ Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

QSurfaceDataArray *data = new QSurfaceDataArray;
QSurfaceDataRow *dataRow1 = new QSurfaceDataRow;
QSurfaceDataRow *dataRow2 = new QSurfaceDataRow;

*dataRow1 << QVector3D(0.0f, 0.16f, 0.290f) << QVector3D(0.0f, 0.26f, 0.825f);
*dataRow2 << QVector3D(1.5f, 0.16f, 0.290f) << QVector3D(1.5f, 0.26f, 0.825f);

data->append(dataRow1);
data->append(dataRow2);

QSurface3DSeries *series = new QSurface3DSeries;
graph->addSeries(series);
series->dataProxy()->resetArray(data);

graph->setWidth(800);
graph->setHeight(600);
graph->show();
```

In my understanding, a plane perpendicular to ZOY will be displayed.However,It displayed nothing when I run it. when I use the code from offical document to replace the two datarow with:

```
*dataRow1 << QVector3D(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.5f) << QVector3D(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f); 
*dataRow2 << QVector3D(0.0f, 1.8f, 1.0f) << QVector3D(1.0f, 1.2f, 1.0f);
```

It did work. Is there anything I didn't notice?

Comment: did you see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-qmlspectrogram-example.html) example? Do you want some thing like this in c++ ?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I don’t think this example is My wanted， I want to show 3d Spectral data sampled from a detector as a 3d surface . I want to  know Why the plane composed of datarow1  and dataRow2 is not displayed.